# rsync command does not resume

Tags: command-line, rsync, backup

I use

```
rsync -rP --rsh=ssh user@[ip]:~/datasets/ ./
```

to download a directory containing lots of large files from the server. I want to resume the progress when it is interrupted (by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or network error).

But I found that when I restart `rsync` with the same parameters, it downloads from the very beginning, even when there is an existing file in the local directory. Why? How to use `rsync` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsync` command will not resume properly because the modification times of the remote and local files differ.

You may request that the modification times on the local files are set to the same timestamp as the remote files with `--times` (or `-t`), but most often one uses `--archive` (or `-a`) which implies both `-r` and `-t` as well as a number of other options that are useful when creating an exact copy of a set of files (`-rlptgoD`):

```
rsync --archive -P user@server:datasets/ ./
```

Note that `--rsh=ssh` is the default and that unless the remote server is set up in a peculiar way, you will not need to use `~` to get your home directory.